# How do I filter a view with a contextual filters on a custom date field?

Tags: views

I am using the Quicktabs module to filter out posted that have a field value that in the date range specified. If you have a better solution in mind, please let me know. I am running Views 3.5 and Drupal 7.16

[QuickTabs layout](http://www.devin-clark.com/share/Edit_quicktab_%7C_TasteDC-20121214-160539.jpg)
I should be able to pass arguments to it to generate the new date sorted views using a contextual filter on the view.
[Contextual Filters](http://www.devin-clark.com/share/http___www.devin-clark.com_share_Events_Content__7C_TasteDC-20121214-161519-20121214-222447.jpg)
I was able to query with the other contextual filters just fine but the date doesn't want to work at all.
What I would like to do is have a tab 4 date ranges (see first image) and clicking on the tab would load the content items with a that take place in a the range of specified dates. How can I get this to work? Is there a url query that I can pass as the argument for the start date field?

Comment: Is the problem only when you try to use it with contextual filters, or does the view not output the way you'd like at all? What happens when you set the contextual filter to show a list when no argument is received and view in a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the arguments follow the pattern

```
20130904--20130930
```

for date range between 4th September and the rest of the month.